# Spark as A Service Using Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka, akka-http

I've followed a blog for exposing Spark as a WebService using Akka HTTP.

The code works fine when I'm running it independently but fails when I tried to connect it to a Spark Standalone cluster. I did some analysis and many suggested to set host entry and spark-env.sh correctly. I have done all those and still, it's not working.

**Note**: My Spark Version and the Spark version in my pom is also the same and I can submit a job to the same cluster using "spark-submit".

**Host File**

```
10.93.125.98 master
10.93.125.97 cluster-node-2
10.93.125.99 cluster-node-3
```

**Spark Slaves File**

```
master
cluster-node-2
cluster-node-3
```

**Spark Env File**

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=master
```

**Scala Code**

```
object SparkFactory {
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .master(AppConfig.sparkMaster)
    .appName(AppConfig.sparkAppName)
    .getOrCreate

  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val sparkConf = sc.getConf
}
```

The full code is available in the below GitHub repo

https://github.com/spoddutur/spark-as-service-using-embedded-server

Getting the below error when I'm trying to connect to the spark cluster. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
[service-user@10.93.125.98 cloud]$ java -jar spark-with-scala-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar -m spark://master:7077
Press RETURN to stop...
[INFO] [07/10/2019 15:53:49.205] [WebServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(WebServer)] Server online at http://master:8001/
^C[service-user@10.93.125.98 cloud]$ java -jar spark-with-scala-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar -m spark://master:7077
Press RETURN to stop...
[INFO] [07/10/2019 15:56:15.096] [WebServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(WebServer)] Server online at http://master:8001/
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/07/10 15:56:27 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.3
19/07/10 15:56:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/07/10 15:56:28 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: spark-with-scala
19/07/10 15:56:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: service-user
19/07/10 15:56:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: service-user
19/07/10 15:56:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
19/07/10 15:56:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
19/07/10 15:56:28 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(service-user); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(service-user); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/07/10 15:56:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 39006.
19/07/10 15:56:29 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/07/10 15:56:29 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/07/10 15:56:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
19/07/10 15:56:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
19/07/10 15:56:29 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-f77fe9f4-dbb8-49db-bbf2-9fca39e18e11
19/07/10 15:56:30 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 127.2 MB
19/07/10 15:56:30 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/07/10 15:56:30 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
19/07/10 15:56:30 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://master:4040
19/07/10 15:56:30 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://master:7077...
19/07/10 15:56:31 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to master/10.93.125.98:7077 after 79 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
[INFO] [07/10/2019 15:56:47.256] [WebServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(WebServer)] Request timeout encountered for request [GET /count Empty]
19/07/10 15:56:50 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://master:7077...
19/07/10 15:57:10 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://master:7077...
19/07/10 15:57:30 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
19/07/10 15:57:30 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
19/07/10 15:57:30 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://master:4040
19/07/10 15:57:30 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 40701.
19/07/10 15:57:30 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on master:40701
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
19/07/10 15:57:31 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, master, 40701, None)
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager master:40701 with 127.2 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, master, 40701, None)
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, master, 40701, None)
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, master, 40701, None)
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/07/10 15:57:31 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:516)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$Lambda$650.00000000641966D0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at com.learning.spark.SparkFactory$.<init>(SparkFactory.scala:19)
        at com.learning.spark.SparkFactory$.<clinit>(SparkFactory.scala)
        at com.learning.spark.web.HttpService$.<init>(HttpService.scala:13)
        at com.learning.spark.web.HttpService$.<clinit>(HttpService.scala)
        at com.learning.spark.web.WebServer$.$anonfun$routes$12(WebServer.scala:47)
        at com.learning.spark.web.WebServer$$$Lambda$579.000000006405B250.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives.$anonfun$complete$1(RouteDirectives.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives$$Lambda$580.000000006405B700.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResult$2(BasicDirectives.scala:66)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$578.000000006405A3C0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRequestContext$2(BasicDirectives.scala:43)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$577.0000000064059D40.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$2(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$563.00000000640532B0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:26)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$2(BasicDirectives.scala:72)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$558.0000000064050AA0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$Lambda$553.000000006404E0B0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$.$anonfun$asyncHandler$1(Route.scala:86)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$$$Lambda$419.00000000ED29C4C0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$31.onPush(Ops.scala:1375)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:409)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Uncaught error from thread [WebServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[WebServer]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:146)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:135)
        at com.learning.spark.web.HttpService$.<init>(HttpService.scala:13)
        at com.learning.spark.web.HttpService$.<clinit>(HttpService.scala)
        at com.learning.spark.web.WebServer$.$anonfun$routes$12(WebServer.scala:47)
        at com.learning.spark.web.WebServer$$$Lambda$579.000000006405B250.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives.$anonfun$complete$1(RouteDirectives.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives$$Lambda$580.000000006405B700.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResult$2(BasicDirectives.scala:66)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$578.000000006405A3C0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRequestContext$2(BasicDirectives.scala:43)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$577.0000000064059D40.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$2(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$563.00000000640532B0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:26)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$2(BasicDirectives.scala:72)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$558.0000000064050AA0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$Lambda$553.000000006404E0B0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$.$anonfun$asyncHandler$1(Route.scala:86)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$$$Lambda$419.00000000ED29C4C0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$31.onPush(Ops.scala:1375)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:409)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:516)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$Lambda$650.00000000641966D0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at com.learning.spark.SparkFactory$.<init>(SparkFactory.scala:19)
        at com.learning.spark.SparkFactory$.<clinit>(SparkFactory.scala)
        ... 57 more
19/07/10 15:57:31 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[ERROR] [SECURITY][07/10/2019 15:57:31.461] [WebServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(WebServer)] Uncaught error from thread [WebServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[WebServer]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:146)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:135)
        at com.learning.spark.web.HttpService$.<init>(HttpService.scala:13)
        at com.learning.spark.web.HttpService$.<clinit>(HttpService.scala)
        at com.learning.spark.web.WebServer$.$anonfun$routes$12(WebServer.scala:47)
        at com.learning.spark.web.WebServer$$$Lambda$579.000000006405B250.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives.$anonfun$complete$1(RouteDirectives.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives$$Lambda$580.000000006405B700.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute$$anon$1.apply(StandardRoute.scala:19)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResult$2(BasicDirectives.scala:66)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$578.000000006405A3C0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRequestContext$2(BasicDirectives.scala:43)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$577.0000000064059D40.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$2(RouteConcatenation.scala:47)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$563.00000000640532B0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:45)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:26)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation.$anonfun$$tilde$1(RouteConcatenation.scala:44)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteConcatenation$RouteWithConcatenation$$Lambda$396.00000000ED210970.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$mapRouteResultWith$2(BasicDirectives.scala:72)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$558.0000000064050AA0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives.$anonfun$handleExceptions$2(ExecutionDirectives.scala:32)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$Lambda$553.000000006404E0B0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives.$anonfun$textract$2(BasicDirectives.scala:159)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.BasicDirectives$$Lambda$394.00000000ED20F650.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$.$anonfun$asyncHandler$1(Route.scala:86)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route$$$Lambda$419.00000000ED29C4C0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$31.onPush(Ops.scala:1375)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:409)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:516)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$Lambda$650.00000000641966D0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at com.learning.spark.SparkFactory$.<init>(SparkFactory.scala:19)
        at com.learning.spark.SparkFactory$.<clinit>(SparkFactory.scala)
        ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the above issue fixed. Sharing the root cause for others reference and to save time.

The root cause is, I am using Spark 2.4.3 and it's internally using Scala 2.11 and the Scala project I'm using is having Scala 2.12. This was creating all the problems the whole time.

I have downgraded the Scala version in my project to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks minimal reproducible example, tail of the stacktrace and even a link to the article you are referring to.

But from what I can see you don't instantiate an instance of `SparkContext` in your application.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Spark. I just downloaded the code from git and used it. I have already attached the Github link where you can find the working code. I have also attached the error stack trace.

Comment: I believe it's not entire stacktrace. There should be valuable information below.

Comment: sorry about it. Updated the entire error stack trace.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on. But It would be definitely less error-prone if the SparkContext was instantiated in the main thread instead of an akka thread. I suggest instantiate SparkContext directly in the beginning of the program and then pass to the web service as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Also running Spark via `extends App` can cause strange bugs related to scala `DelayedInit` sometimes. Creating an oldschool `def main(args: Array[String])` method works better.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. do you have any sample working project which i can use for reference?

Comment: Unfortunately no small opensource projects

Comment: Thanks. I tried with spark context also. Doesn't work.

Comment: Finally, I got it fixed. I'm using Spark 2.4.3 and it's internally using Scala 2.11 and the Scala project I'm using to join the cluster is having Scala 2.12.  This was creating all the problems the whole time. I have downgraded the Scala version in my project to get it work.